# Go Along With The Ride?

Tags: idioms

I watched the interview with Alexander Wang on Youtube.
In the video, he said 'The people in the industry are crazy enough to *go along with the ride* because they love it so much'

I looked up the dictionary but there's only go along "for" the ride.

Both are the same meaning?

Answer (score 2):

Alexander Wang made an error, as people sometimes do when making speeches or recording videos. The usual expression meaning 'join in an activity without playing an important part in it' is [go along for the ride](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/come-go-be-along-for-the-ride).

He possibly became momentarily confused because there is a similar idiom, [go along with](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-along-with-sth-sb?q=go%20along%20with), meaning 'to support an idea, or to agree with someone's opinion'.

Comment: Thank you so much, Michael! Your answer helped me a lot! Have a good day